# Не работает программа с массивом на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо по заданию решить следующую задачу: Дан массив `A` размера `N`.

- Вывести вначале его элементы с нечетными номерами в порядке возрастания номеров.
- Вывести элементы с четными номерами в порядке убывания номеров.

Написал следующую программу, но она выдает ошибки.

```
import math
N = int (input ("Введите число N: "))
a = []
a = [0] * N
for i in range(len(a)):
    i = str(i + 1)
    print("Введите элемент массива " + i + ": ", end = " ")
    i = int(i)
    i = i - 1
    a[i] = int(input())
print("Массив: " + str(a))
while i<=N:
   print(str(a[i]))
   i=i+2 
N=N/2
for i in range(1,N,-1):
    print(str(a[i*2]))
```

Comment: Вам что, в первом цикле из переменных только i выдали?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых делить целые числа надо через `//` чтобы получались целые числа иначе будут числа с плавающей запятой и полезут ошибки, т.е. вместо

```
N=N/2
```

надо

```
N = N // 2
```

Во вторых не лучше ли получать элементы массива каким-нибудь более удобным способом? Например в одну строку:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

тогда не нужно будет устраивать такой изврат как развели вы

Ну и в третьих задачку можно попробовать сделать в пару строчек:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

res = list(map(lambda j: j[1], filter(lambda i: i[0] % 2 != 0, enumerate(arr)))) + list(map(lambda j: j[1], filter(lambda i: i[0] % 2 == 0, enumerate(arr))))[::-1]

print(*res)
```

Comment: Изврат это как раз таки сокращать такие вещи в одну строку. Вам это понятней: `a=list((int(input(f"Введите {i} элемент массива: ")) for i in range(0, int(input("Введите число N: ")))))`, или все таки в подробном варианте?

Answer (score 2):

В питоне не принято использовать адресную арифметику без необходимости. Есть более изящные методы:

```
n = int(input("Введите число N: "))
a = [int(input("Введите элемент массива {}: ".format(i + 1)))
     for i in range(n)]

print("Массив:", a)

# items on odd indices ascending
for v in a[1::2]:
    print(v)

# items on even indices descending
for v in reversed(a[::2]):
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нумерация начинается с 1

```
N = int (input ("Введите число N: "))
a = []
for i in range(N) :
    print("Введите элемент массива " + str(i + 1) + ": ", end = " ")
    a.append(int(input()))
print("Массив: " + str(a))
for i in range(N) :
if a[i] % 2 :
    print(a[i])
for i in range(N - 1, -1, -1) :
    if not a[i] % 2 :
        print(a[i])
```

В моем коде номера это индексы

Получаем что нечетные элементы по порядку с начала списка, четные с конца списка